# UItableView automaticDimension not working on custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know this is a question that was asked a lot here, but I tried all the solutions I found and none of them worked

Here's the content of my custom  UITableViewCell

[image]
[image]

Here's the properties of the label

[image: Label properties]

And its constraints :

[image]

Here's the switch's constraints

[image]

In the controller viewDidLoad, I have :

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension //scale height to content
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

which as far as I know, should be enough.

But the result is :

[image]

As you can see, only the first line of the label is displayed.

Like I said before, I tried multiples solutions I found here like :

- checking the constraints
- adding tableView.reloadData() to the viewDidLoad
- overriding heightForRowAt with "return UITableView.automaticDimension"
- adding cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints() and cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded() before returning the cell in cellForRowAt
  and the result is always the same.
  The only things that partially worked are :
- removing the bottom constraint of the label
  [image]
- or giving a numeric value to tableView.rowHeight, which obviously won't work if the content change.

So what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` is bound to `cell.contentView` top and bottom by 8

AND

`Label` is bound to `cell.contentView` top and bottom by 8

Autolayout tries to respect both and layout has issues determining expected height.

Try removing top and bottom spacing for `Switch` and have it vertically centered in container, that should resolve the issue.